# MYSQL rotate a returned data

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm getting a data that return like this:

```
| id |   name    |
| 1  | customer1 |
| 2  | customer2 |
| 3  | customer3 |
| 4  | customer4 |
```

Now I want to rotate it so it return like this:

```
| id |   name    |
| 3  | customer3 |
| 4  | customer4 |
| 1  | customer1 |
| 2  | customer2 |
```

How can i Achieve it in MYSQL?

Comment: I'm trying to get the next row after the last index that has been taken. for example i have ended a loop in `customer2`, so i need to continue to `customer3`. 
sorry, if I can't explain it influently

Comment: note that it can't use the same query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. If you need to sort it like 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3

Use this query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM customers
ORDER BY id >= 4 DESC, id;
```

Comment: this may get the id `4` into the first row, but what i want too is the next id after `4` should be the `5, 6` and so on. and after the data runs out, it goes back to id '1, 2, 3 ...'
so it return the data with following order: `4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3 ...`

Comment: Changed the answer

Comment: fantastic! this has saved my day. if you don't mind, can you explain how the query works?
again, thank you very much for your help! I really appreciate it

Comment: This query uses sorting by 2 fields. The first field is calculated as boolean expression `is id greater or equals to 4` if it is not, then the value would be `0` if greater, then `1`. So DESC keyword is needed to reverse the order of first sorting argument. The second is just an ID field. So it sorts by the first field first and then sorts by the second field. This puts all numbers less then 4  after all the numbers greater or equals to 4.

Answer (score 0):

i think this code you need

```
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

> replace `ASC` by `DESC` for get id descending

Comment: This will make the data reversed, but it won't possible if i want a specific id from the data to be the first. But nevermind that it, already answered, thanks for answering

Comment: The important thing is that you found the solution. :)